# install.package("matlib") shows non-zero exit status error in RStudio

Tags: r, ubuntu

I tried install.package() function as well as install through tar.gz file but every time it shows the same error which is `non-zero exit status`.
Please someone can tell how to download matlib? I have `R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10) -- "Wooden Christmas-Tree"` installed in Ubuntu 16.04.

```
Error::::::::

> install.packages("matlib")
Installing package into ‘/home/harsh/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  dependency ‘car’ is not available
--2020-08-03 15:07:43--  https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/matlib_0.9.3.tar.gz
Resolving cran.rstudio.com (cran.rstudio.com)... 2600:9000:21f0:8000:6:c2d3:f940:93a1, 2600:9000:21f0:8600:6:c2d3:f940:93a1, 2600:9000:21f0:9800:6:c2d3:f940:93a1, ...
Connecting to cran.rstudio.com (cran.rstudio.com)|2600:9000:21f0:8000:6:c2d3:f940:93a1|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 220211 (215K) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘/tmp/Rtmpb8wWqf/downloaded_packages/matlib_0.9.3.tar.gz’

     0K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 23%  428K 0s
    50K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 46%  457K 0s
   100K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 69%  217K 0s
   150K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 93%  487K 0s
   200K .......... .....                                      100%  500K=0.6s

2020-08-03 15:07:44 (365 KB/s) - ‘/tmp/Rtmpb8wWqf/downloaded_packages/matlib_0.9.3.tar.gz’ saved [220211/220211]

ERROR: dependency ‘car’ is not available for package ‘matlib’
* removing ‘/home/harsh/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/matlib’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘matlib’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmpb8wWqf/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: Try first installing the `car`package anf then `matlib`.

Answer (score 1):

Installing a package should install its dependencies. If this fails, you may need to manually install the dependencies. Installing the `car` package may fail if the current version of `car` needs a newer version of `R` than what you are using. The `R.Version()` function will tell you which `R` version you are using. You may need to update to the current version of `R` before installing `car`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `cmake` was missing under Ubuntu. The installation from the console is as follows `sudo apt install cmake`.